# Writing 16 bit/pixel data to QuickTime movie via AVFoundation

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, avfoundation

I'm trying to write a CGImage containing data loaded from a 16 bit-per-pixel TIFF file out to a ProRes 44444 QuickTime file while maintaining bit depth.

I'm loading the data like this:

```
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/whatever/test.tif"];
CGImageRef temp = [image CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:nil hints:nil];
```

I have an AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor set up as follows:

```
NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_64ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                                                       nil];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary];
```

Then I write my image to a CVPixelBuffer:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width, size.height, 16, 8*size.width, rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
```

And then append that to a movie:

```
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:pxbuffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frame, 24)]
```

This worked perfectly with 8 bit/pixel images (with values tweaked appropriately), but with 16 bit/pixel images, I get bizarre color in the resulting QuickTime movie. It looks a little like some channels might be swapped, but various attempts to swap them around haven't produced useful results. Does anyone have a working example of writing greater than 8 bit/pixel image data out to a QuickTime movie?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found a solution, and I thought I'd post it since the the public Internet appears to contain zero examples of this, and I had to try a lot of things before I hit on something that worked.

Here's how to get a kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16 CVPixelBuffer (what you want for writing ProRes 4444), starting with a CGImage. This works for 16 bit/channel RGB sources with no alpha. It likely could be made to work for images with alpha channels by changing bitmapInfo and bitsPerPixel values, but this is untested.

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) convertFrame:(CGImageRef) sourceImage {
    vImage_Buffer sourceBuffer;
    CVPixelBufferRef destBuffer;

    vImage_CGImageFormat inFormat = {
        .bitsPerComponent = (unsigned int)CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(sourceImage),
        .bitsPerPixel = (unsigned int)CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(sourceImage),
        .colorSpace = NULL,
        .bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNone,
        .version = 0,
        .decode = NULL,
        .renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault,
    };

    vImage_Error err = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceBuffer, &inFormat, NULL, sourceImage, kvImageNoFlags);

    if (err == kvImageNoError)
    {
        CGColorSpaceRef dstColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceITUR_709);

        vImage_CGImageFormat format = {
            .bitsPerComponent = 16,
            .bitsPerPixel = 48,
            .bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNone,
            .colorSpace = dstColorSpace,
        };

        vImageCVImageFormatRef vformat = vImageCVImageFormat_Create(kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16,
                                                                    kvImage_ARGBToYpCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2,
                                                                    kCVImageBufferChromaLocation_Center,
                                                                    dstColorSpace,
                                                                    0);

        CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage), CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                                              kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16, NULL, &destBuffer);

        NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && destBuffer != NULL);

        err = vImageBuffer_CopyToCVPixelBuffer(&sourceBuffer, &format, destBuffer, vformat, 0, kvImagePrintDiagnosticsToConsole);

        if(err != 0)
            NSLog(@"Conversion error: %zi", err);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(dstColorSpace);
        free(sourceBuffer.data);
    }

    return destBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Just FYI, but you have a memory leak there, just adding this release before the colorspace release: vImageCVImageFormat_Release(vformat)

Comment: Also note that the docs for vImageCVImageFormat_Create() state that the colorspace for the source image should be passed as the value of the baseColorspace, so in this case it should be sRGB if you want the default gamma conversion to be applied.

Comment: FYI you can write ProRes with kCVPixelFormatType_64ARGB on Intel Macs, but need to use kCVPixelFormatType_64RGBALE on Apple Silicon to be able to work on MacBook M1 Pro/Max due to the HW accelerators.